# Two TVs and two satellite TV receivers Blown in three months

Tags: electrical

My home has a good grounding using underground copper plates. In three months I lost two TVs (Phillips old tube type) and the satellite receiver boxes attached to each. Both TVs had the Audio/Video Out sections on the main boards burnt out, while one receiver had its  Audio/Video Out section blown.

Some facts:
1) Both receivers connected to the same 8 foot dish with a dual output LNB
2) Both TVs were fed by the same TV Cable(Coax) using a splitter at the main line.
3) TV cable (Coax)sometimes shows voltages as high as 12 VAC. The main line Coax when removed from coax showed 24 volts yesterday, the splitter dropped it 12 VAC

The technician said the Audio Video sections blow out due to volatages from Dish induced by lightening, but the Tuner section  of the receiver where the satellite cable enters the receiver is OK. Howcome Audio Video of both the TV and the satellite receiver get burnt at the same time.Where can be the source of burning voltage. I have new TV but will not connect to Cable Tv of satellite receiver unltil the problem source is identified. Please help in this regard soon so that I can watch TV.

Answer (score 3):

Add a lightning arrester and grounding block to your satellite cables.  bond it well to the ground plate.